# Spark job failing with exception: "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack Exception Details:

Tags: apache-spark

18/07/20 17:34:40 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@29cfd92b{/metrics/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/apache/spark/rdd/RDDOperationScope$.()V @23: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/DefaultScalaModule$' (current frame, stack[2]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @23
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/apache/spark/rdd/RDDOperationScope$' }
    stack: { 'org/apache/spark/rdd/RDDOperationScope$', 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper', 'com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/DefaultScalaModule$' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab7 010e 2ab3 0110 2ab8 0114 2abb 0074
    0x0000010: 59b7 0115 b201 1ab6 011e b500 692a bb00
    0x0000020: 8059 03b7 0121 b500 6cb1

```
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:693)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.textFile(SparkContext.scala:822)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.textFile(JavaSparkContext.scala:172)
at SimpleApp.main(SimpleApp.java:11)
```

18/07/20 17:34:40 INFO spark.SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook

Comment: Please provide context for this exception and edit your post to separate text and actual stacktrace after that.

Comment: I am trying to do HW program in Spark. My class simple as below

Comment: i couldn't paste the class, it says too long..